# Random Number Guessing Game - Player Logging

Tags: java, database-connection

I was creating this Random Number Guessing Game and found out that I needed to store the username, time and date that user played, and his score.

Here's the code I wrote regarding this logic I'm trying to create:

This is the codes for the connection:

```
Connection cn=null;
ResultSet rs=null;
Statement stat=null;
Statement statement=null;
```

The insert statement im using:

```
            int ok;
            try
            {
                ok=statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO Table1(Player_name,Play_date, Player_score) VALUES("+'"'+username+","+datetime+","+scoretodb+'"'+")");
            }catch(SQLException bleh){}
```

And here's the Connection function im using:

```
public void setConnection()
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                cn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:db1");
                stat=cn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);
                rs=stat.executeQuery("Select Player_name,Play_date,Player_score from Table1");
                rs.next();
            }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){}
        }catch(SQLException sqle){}
    }
```

The logic I'm trying to make here is that in every button click of the button I made for the purpose of writing a new record into my db which contains the following fields:

```
Player_name, Play_date, Play_score
```

which obviously requires the players' username, date and time when he played, and his/her score.

But when I executed the query stated above(code), and click the button assigned for writing a new record, the button kind of sticks to the panel(which obviously is a sign for an error which im still thinking of what kind it might be) and the database doesn't have the values I have entered. By the way, my db is already connected to my program. and the username comes from a JTextField = txtuser, the date/time comes from the following code:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    //get current date time with Date()
    Date date = new Date();
```

and the users' score comes from userscore=Integer

How can I make it write a new record into my db? Is that possible with the code I've provided on this question?

Comment: Do you have an error? what is the problem?

Comment: Do you have an error in the StackTrace?

Answer (score 2):

Well for starters, you should not just ignore exceptions like you are doing:

```
       }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){}
    }catch(SQLException sqle){}
```

Try something like this:

```
       }catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){
           cnfe.printStackTrace();
       }
    }catch(SQLException sqle){
        sqle.printStackTrace();
    }
```

That way the software at least has an opportunity to give you some feedback if something goes wrong in the `try` block.  (Note that your program must be run with 'java.exe' (not 'javaw.exe') so that you can see the exceptions printed to the console.)

Also the fact that the button is sticking down indicates that the button action handler code is throwing an exception.  So write a try/catch block in your button action handler:

```
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            try
            {
                // your code here
            }
            catch(Throwable t)
            {
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Hopefully you should start seeing an exception and a stack trace, which is usually the first step towards isolating what the problem is.

Comment: _error points at the period. what could have caused it?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  If you have a stack trace, copy and paste it.

Comment: i have a stack trace. i tried it since you suggested it would catch the errors that came with my code. but t.printStackTrace(); is caught as an error i meant, the error is pointing at the period after the "t"

Comment: Sorry I don't know why that would happen.  The code works fine for me.